# How to exclude assemblies before registering them in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I can't exclude some assemblies in install process.

I try this :

```
 public class InternationnalisationInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container, Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
        var filter = new AssemblyFilter(path)
                .FilterByAssembly(a => !a.IsDynamic
                    && !a.FullName.Contains("Microsoft"));

        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(filter)
            .BasedOn<ITraductionProvider>()               
            .WithService.AllInterfaces());
    }
}
```

in dev no problem, but in production :

> Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
>   à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
>   à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
>   à Castle.Core.Internal.ReflectionUtil.GetAvailableTypes(Assembly assembly, Boolean includeNonExported)
>   à Castle.Core.Internal.ReflectionUtil.GetAvailableTypesOrdered(Assembly assembly, Boolean includeNonExported)
>   à Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.FromAssemblyDescriptor.b__0(Assembly a)
>   à System.Linq.Enumerable.d__14 2.MoveNext()
>   à Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.FromDescriptor.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal kernel)
>   à Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.BasedOnDescriptor.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal kernel)
>   à Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Register(IRegistration[] registrations)
>   à Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Register(IRegistration[] registrations)
>   à Internationnalisation.InternationnalisationInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)

this assembly is used to tag class for VSIX registration.
Can you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: If it's needed, maybe just don't exclude it?

Comment: Can you translate the error message to english?

Comment: Sriram : FileNotFoundException

Comment: Jester : Not needed in production, just needed to do VSIX package for developers

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from an app where I load explicitly my assemblies for integration tests. You can add/edit this [LINQ to Entiteis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386964%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) query whatever you want. :

```
DirectoryInfo areasFolder = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\Areas"));
FileInfo[] assemblyFiles =
                        areasFolder.EnumerateDirectories()
                            .SelectMany(d => d.EnumerateFiles("*.dll"))
                            .Where(f => f.Name.Contains("MyAppNamespace"))
                            .GroupBy(f => f.Name.Substring(0, f.Name.Length - f.Extension.Length))
                            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTimeUtc).First())
                            .ToArray();
```